# Traverse FQL Result on PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-fql

I'am having a lot of issues understanding how json works. I create a FQL query to Facebook and I receive the correct response, but I just can't seem to parse it. This is what I get

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value": {
        "M.25-34": 3392, 
        "M.35-44": 2601, 
        "M.45-54": 1675, 
        "M.55-64": 863, 
        "M.18-24": 625, 
        "M.65+": 552, 
        "F.25-34": 531, 
        "F.35-44": 328, 
        "F.45-54": 159, 
        "M.13-17": 119, 
        "F.18-24": 104, 
        "F.55-64": 74, 
        "F.65+": 51, 
        "F.13-17": 35, 
        "U.45-54": 8, 
        "U.35-44": 3, 
        "U.25-34": 2, 
        "U.65+": 1
      }, 
      "metric": "page_fans_gender_age"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I need to traverse the array with the values. But I not only need the values, but the "key" part as well. I would like to be able to create a graph with it so I need both key+value.

I have tried:

```
$fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);
echo $fqlResult[0]["M.25-34"];
```

And also `json_encode($fqlResult)` or `json_decode($fqlResult)` but no available. How can I get the `key->value` pairs?

**EDIT**

I eventually managed to get the inner array values. However it seems too harcoded. I plainly took the first element of the data array and traverse it.

```
    foreach($fqlResult[0] as $theKey => $theValue){
    if(is_array($theValue)){
        foreach($theValue as $theKey2 => $theValue2){
                echo("The key2: " . $theKey2 . " The value2: " . $theValue2 . "<BR>");
        }// 2 level
    }// if array
}// 1 level
```

It does the trick. Maybe there can be a better way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
while($element = current($fqlResult[0])) {
    echo "key: " . key($array);
    echo "-> value: " . $element . "\n";
    next($array);
}
```

Prints all `key -> value` pairs inside `$fqlResult[0]`.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane  As it turns out, the json response I posted, is an array but with only two elements: "value" and "metric". Following your answer helped me to notice it. However, I still need to get the data inside the first element: value. I assume that they are not members of an array, but attributes right? How can I access them, assuming I don't know what the names of those attributes are?  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped. I think the code in your last edit is the direct answer to your question.